# Why do you need to dereference the char pointer?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I don't understand why the pointer has to be de-referenced here. `char *toParseStr = (char*)malloc(10);` Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

`char *toParseStr = (char*)malloc(10);`

There is no dereference here but a cast of the `malloc` return value to `char *`. The cast is not required and even should be avoided.

To know why the cast should be avoided:

http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Comment: Are there any benefits of casting it? And in what situation would it be useful?

Comment: @AkshaiShah It's a style issue, some coders prefer to be explicit in their casts.  Also, if you want it to work in C++ as well it requires the cast.

Comment: @AkshaiShah In c++ the cast is required and I've seen people get into the habit from doing it there; but then using `malloc` in c++ should be a rare event.

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @mux - The only time you would cast the result of `malloc` is if you are working in C++, or you are using a C compiler that predates the 1989 standard.  Prior to C89, `malloc` returned `char *`, not `void *`, so in those days a cast *was* required if the target type was not `char *`.  The reason the `void *` type exists is to provide a "generic" object pointer type that can be converted to other object pointer types without needing the cast.

Comment: @JohnBode yes I've read the who discussion so I know the pros and cons, that's why I thought that question should be added :)

Answer (score -2):

malloc returns a void*, so the cast is necessary in some cases to prevent compilation errors

Comment: No, the cast is not necessary and even harmful. It would have been necessary if it was C++.

Comment: the link ouah just posted explains this.

Comment: Cast is not necessary in C.